# Updating map attributes

Tags: javascript, maps, yui, mapbox

I´m trying to "ease" a mapbox map. Pretty sure this is not specific to mapbox.js

Basically I take the map via the id and then call properties on it, but these won´t update the map.

I can recreate the problem in DOM console on [taking this example](http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/optimal-easing/).

[image: a busy cat]

On my app I have a function that updates the map, and I use the same logic: get the map via the identifier and then call properties to move it.

What am I missing?

Thanks!!

In my code I have a YUI autocomplete field, and neither of the "on" or "after" work:

```
function addMeasureInput() {
YUI().use("autocomplete", "autocomplete-filters", "autocomplete-highlighters", function(Y) {
    //skin
    Y.one('body').addClass('yui3-skin-sam');
    //Array source
    var locs = getLocationsList();
    Y.one('#ac-input').plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
        resultFilters: 'phraseMatch',
        resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
        source: locs,
        on: {
            select: function() {
             console.log("Location Selected!");
                             var map = mapbox.map('map');
             map.ease.location({ lat: 0, lon: 0 }).zoom(5).optimal();
            }
        },
        after: {
            select: function(o) {
                var map = mapbox.map('map');
                map.ease.location({ lat: 0, lon: 0 }).zoom(5).optimal();
                showLoc(o.result.raw);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

};

Comment: Can you post some example code of how you are implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

`mapbox.map('map')` must just create map: http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v0.6.7/#mapbox.map:

```
Create a map on the current page.
```

When I get map DOM element `document.getElementById('map')` I don't found any links to mapbox map instance. So probably you can't get exist map instance by DOM. However it's a bad idea save your own javascript objects in DOM elements.

Better save your map instance as javascript object. For your mapbox exaple http://mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/optimal-easing/ `map` instance stored in `window` object. So you can just write:

```
map.ease.location({ lat: 38.9, lon: -77 }).zoom(10).optimal();
```

or

```
map.zoomIn();
```

and etc. It's will work.

**UPD:**
As I understood for you better use something like lazy initialization:

```
var map = null;

function ease (lat, lon, zoom) {
    if (!map) {
        map = mapbox.map('map');
    }
    map.ease.location({ lat: lat, lon: lon }).zoom(zoom).optimal();
}

function addMeasureInput() {
    YUI().use("autocomplete", "autocomplete-filters",
              "autocomplete-highlighters", function(Y) {
        //skin
        Y.one('body').addClass('yui3-skin-sam');
        //Array source
        var locs = getLocationsList();
        Y.one('#ac-input').plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
            resultFilters: 'phraseMatch',
            resultHighlighter: 'phraseMatch',
            source: locs,
            on: {
                select: function() {
                    console.log("Location Selected!");
                    ease(0, 0, 5);
                }
            },
            after: {
                select: function(o) {
                    ease(0, 0, 5);
                    showLoc(o.result.raw);
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But however map initialization it's a very slow operation (create dom, load tiles), so better initialize map once and probably not on demand.

Comment: I´ve added the part of from my code that is trying to make that. The problem is that the Mapbox example ties that to the onClick() event, where I am already inside the function that triggered the event (the YUI search field).